# Shirt Pattern making

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, print-design, illustration, image-trace

I like to draw, and I've drawn this yesterday:

[image: Sample image]

[Large image](http://cl.ly/AM1n).

I want to make this a T-Shirt, so I need to make this drawing a vector. I want to make it different, not the regular vector-drawn shape.

Do you know where I can find some inspiration and tutorials on how to actually make this an awesome T-shirt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is a great tutorial for you which will get you started:
http://www.gomediazine.com/tutorials/from-sketch-to-vector-illustration/

And here are some more tutorials on sketch to vector:
http://deltadesignz.com/2010/11/15-sketches-to-illustration-tutorials/